# SQL query optimizer

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I can not understand anything. I have Oracle 11g db with alot of data and tables. I want to join some tables and output result of it.
Ok, just wrote:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Table1_Id = Table1.Table1_Id
WHERE Table2.Column1=1
```

- very simple, but too slow.
  Ok, Table2 connected with Table3. This table contain some flag in column, which can tell us, that it generly connected with Table1.
  I wrote next code:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM Table1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Table1_Id = Table1.Table1_Id
  LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Table3_Id = Table2_Table3_Id
  WHERE
  Table3.ColumnWithFlag LIKE '%some id info about Table1%'
  AND Table2.Column1=1
  ```

and this query have low cost and faster then first query. Why, I can not understand? I use 3 tables in my query and it work faster, then query with 2 tables (rowcount the same, data the same).

Comment: When OUTER JOIN, do not put the outer table's conditions in the WHERE clause, put them in the ON clause instead. (Otherwise it's a regular inner join that is performed.)

Comment: @jarlh, when outer joining, predicates in ON clause and Where clause are very different by nature. You should be very careful to not get incorrect result. In where it will filter rows, while in ON it won't

Comment: There is an added condition in the 2nd query, the `Table3.ColumnWithFlag LIKE '%some id info about Table1%'` which I assume filters most of the data from your result set, but still this is text parsing and `LIKE` is not very efficient at doing this operation. But this is just speculation. It's best to compare execution plans of the two queries to see where the "bottleneck" is.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, author mentioned that both selects return same result

Comment: Radu, this is just little sample. My original query is large and dificultly, and, as I already wrote: "this query have low cost" (result of PL\SQL Developer), and I can not understand why

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, yes, it's a difference. But in this specific case, doesn't the where clause conditions make the outer join return the same result as an inner join?

Comment: @jarlh, nope... in inner join you can write predicates in ON clause , or move them to where clause. In outer join, if you have where some = 1 it will filter joining result, if you move where to ON it will not filter, it will return all rows but place NULLs where condition is not true

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, sorry if I'm a bit slow today (Monday), but can you link to example or other description why "t1 left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.col2 = value" is different from "t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.col2 = value"?

Comment: @jarlh, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68b32/423
last statement will produce all 3 rows

Comment: Oh, I forgot to write my opinion: Table2 contain a lot of rows (several billion), which are not connected with Table1; may be optimizer in second query first of all filtering Table2 by Table3 info (this is just several million rows) and then join it to Table1.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, thank you for the sqlfiddle, but as far as I can see it just confirms that the LEFT keyword in this case can be replaced with INNER when the t2.SomeValues = 'A' condition is placed in the WHERE clause. (Or am I just plain stupid today?)

Comment: @jarlh, I think we are talking about the same things :) probably we misunderstood each other.

Comment: @Mixim Some of us surely would like you to spool and attach your explain plans (e.g. `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR (your_query);` `SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY)`).

Answer (score 2):

First, some basics.  This is your first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 t2 
     ON t2.Table1_Id = t1.Table1_Id
WHERE t2.Column1 = 1;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary, because the `WHERE` clause turns it into an `INNER JOIN` anyway.  If there is no match, then `t2.Column1` is `NULL` and it gets filtered out.

I could imagine at least one way that you could see this performance issue.  Basically, if `Table2` has no index on `Table1_Id` but it does have an index on `Table3_Id`.

In this case, the first query plan would need to scan `Table2` (perhaps using an index on `Column1`) and then do database magic -- probably a hash join on the tables.

The second query would join `Table2` and `Table3` using available indexes.  This would be (presumably) much smaller than just `Table2`. The database magic would be spared a full table scan of a very large table.

This is one possible scenario.  The real way is to look at the execution plan for the queries to see what is different.

Comment: I think the same, but I can not understand "how Oracle understand, that he should 'remove' unrequired rows from Table2".

Comment: @Mixim . . . It is a question of how the rows are accessed in the query.  The first query might give Oracle only one way to access them -- by scanning all the rows in the table.  The second might give Oracle another access method using an index.